# Is there a way to prevent formControl from triggering event?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have 3 fields linked with forms which type is number, when I modify field A, it modifies field B and C, when I modify field B it modifies field A and C and when I modify field C it modifies field A and B accordingly.

my component is as below :

```
this.form= this.formBuilder.group({
   fieldA: new FormControl(this.valueA),
   fieldB: new FormControl(this.valueB),
   fieldC: new FormControl(this.valueC),
});

onFieldAchanged() {
   //Do some calculs
   this.form.get('fieldB').setValue(x);
   this.form.get('fieldC').setValue(y);
}

onFieldBchanged() {
   //Do some calculs
   this.form.get('fieldA').setValue(x);
   this.form.get('fieldC').setValue(y);
}

onFieldCchanged() {
   //Do some calculs
   this.form.get('fieldA').setValue(x);
   this.form.get('fieldB').setValue(y);
}
```

and my template as below :

```
<input formControlName="fieldA" type="number" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onFieldAchanged()"/>
<input formControlName="fieldB" type="number" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onFieldBchanged()"/>
<input formControlName="fieldC" type="number" class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onFieldCchanged()"/>
```

The problems come when you modify one of the field, it goes into a loop and makes the app crash.

I already tried to add the parameter `emitEvent: false` in my `setValue()` but it changed nothing

So my question: Is there a way to prevent the triggering of the other functions ? When I modify `fieldA` I just want to enter in my `onFieldAchanged()` function and set the two others values, no more.

Thank you for your help

Comment: maybe you should look into the crashing issue rather than preventing it from happening. Your app should be able to have inputs.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't looks like a normal use case to loop like this every time I change a value no ?

Comment: Did you try patch value on reactive form?

Comment: Why are you using the ngModelChange event when you're using a form control? That's probably why it appears as if emitEvent has no effect. Try using the valuechanges observable on the form control instead.

Comment: @Agudolive it depends, Angular has loop going all the time, internally, so as long as you don't do any heavy process, theres nothings wrong with that

Comment: So, I just tried the patchValue instead of setValue but the result remains the same.

Comment: @Nicolas creating an infinite loop in your app that triggers change detection (as updating an input value and triggering an event does) will always make it crash

Answer (score 14, accepted):

there sure is:

first, instead of using `(ngModelChange)`, use `valueChanges` observable:

```
this.form.get('fieldA').valueChanges.subscribe(v => this.onFieldAchanged());
this.form.get('fieldB').valueChanges.subscribe(v => this.onFieldBchanged());
this.form.get('fieldC').valueChanges.subscribe(v => this.onFieldCchanged());
```

then, add the `emitEvent` option into your `setValue` fuctions to stop their `valueChanges` from emitting:

```
onFieldAchanged() {
   //Do some calculs
   this.form.get('fieldB').setValue(x, {emitEvent: false});
   this.form.get('fieldC').setValue(y, {emitEvent: false});
}
```

the issue is mixing `ngModel` with reactive forms. gotta choose one.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pass a parameter in your onFieldXchanged() function in the template and check for this string to see if the event was triggered from an input being typed or from one of the other eventriggers. Just make a guard.

Answer (score -1):

Weird, I actually did something similar to this myself:

What I did was make two form groups:

```
    this.groupA = this.formBuilder.group({
        fieldA: new FormControl(''),
    });

    this.groupB = this.formBuilder.group({
        fieldB: new FormControl(''),
    });
```

Then I have it set that fieldA's value changes causes fieldB's value to change:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.groupA.get('fieldA').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        this.groupB.get('fieldB').setValue(val);
    });
}
```

Then in my template, fieldA's value is set to fieldB's to complete the sync:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Field A:" formControlName="fieldA [value]="groupB.get('fieldB').value">
```